# Multi tenancy app - how to pass data between front/backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, architecture

I am building this multi tenancy app in Node/Mongoose + React. I decided to have a single database for all users.

I have a top collection called `companies` that stores a company basic data and has a `company_id`.

Entries in other collections like `users`, `inventory` etc. have a reference to the company they belong to via this id. For example the user schema looks like:

```
const UserSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
required: true,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true, select: true },
  role: { type: String, required: true },
  company_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId }, //REFERENCE TO COMPANY
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
});
```

Until here all good. 
How do I now properly pass the company_id around to make sure I only retrieve the relevant data? E.g. if User X belongs to company A he only can see inventory for company A.

I guess I am unsure about step 4:

- 1. A user log in.
  2. He will get back a JWT token that has the `company_id` info on it.
  3. This token will be stored somewhere (I guess local storage or cookies) in the front end
  4. User has to retrieve a list of inventory. Since inventory is a unique big collection, how do I pass that `company_id` to the backend? Considering this is a GET request, I assume it should be passed as a HTTP header? Or should the backend just decode the JWT that is attached with every request and retrieve the `company_id` from there?

Answer (score 0):

You are wise to choose a single database for all your customers.

But, multitenant apps **must conceal your different customers' data from each other.** If possible, they should conceal each others' very existence on your app from each other.

You must validate your JWT or some other security token with **every request**, and you must extract the user's identity and/or the company_id from that token.  With every request. Because cybercreeps.

Your security tokens should be hard to spoof. "Hard" means "hard like guessing a 160-bit random number correctly."

You **must not** believe a request that simply passes the user's id or company id in the request.  It should be impossible for somebody who sees the request, for example

```
 https://example.com/company/123
```

to simply try

```
 https://example.com/company/124
```

to see some other customer's data. Unless you want to be the subject of a feature article on https://krebsonsecurity.com/ .  (You don't.)

Finally, remember that URLs are logged in various proxy servers, and you cannot control those logs.  You should not embed sensitive data in URLs, either as part of API routes or as query parameters.

Comment: thanks I indeed will make sure to attach the jwt with every request. So should I then decode back the same JWT in the backend (for example when creating a new inventory item) and extract the company_id from this JWT? I mean client attach jwt to request, backend decodes JWT and extract company_id